# Boosting a Class Trial character

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I got a free Character Boost for pre-ordering Legion and I was wondering how it worked in conjunction with the new Class Trial feature. According the [Character Boost support article](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/7623), a character that is level 60+ when boosted will also have their primary professions and First Aid skill increased. However, the new Class Trial feature allows to test out a character at level 100 and then spend a boost to unlock it for regular play.

Does a character unlocked from the Class Trial feature have their professions boosted or do they start at the lowest skill level?

Comment: In practice it won't matter much. You can use Legion recipes at skill 1, and getting higher ranks of those recipes is independent of the skill number.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as a side note, profession world quests at level 110 require a profession level of 100, so it is advisable to at least increase the skill a bit. Apart from that, I read that only crafted cosmetics will require a higher skill level, so one is usually fine without a level of 800.

Comment: @BPND That's a good point. The world quests are definitely worth doing, and the crafted cosmetics are going to be worth quite a bit of gold too, at least after a month or two.

Comment: Fishing for example requires a skill of 675 in order to learn Legion Fishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class trial does not qualify for the veteran profession bonus.

You need to level it the old fashioned way up to lvl 60. You can, however, use a different character for this... play the trial until you're comfortable with a class, then level another toon of that class up to 60 and boost that one.

Source: GM

But as it has been pointed out in the comments already it's not that important. 
It *does* matter, since you need a certain profession level (100) to qualify for World Quests, which can be very expensive at the start of an expansion, if you have to buy the required materials. 
If you're going to choose professions you can supply yourself (Herbalism & Alchemy/Inscription or Mining & Blacksmithing, etc) you're free to ignore the veteran bonuses.